# Contentful Validation Error when updating Rich Text field

Tags: c#, data-migration, contentful

I'm migrating a website from an old CMS to Contentful using a C# script. I've exported all articles/entries to a local JSON file and am currently successfully uploading all articles to Contentful.
From there I loop through all entries and fish out all links pointing to assets on the old website([www.oldsite.com/content/thisisafile.pdf](http://www.oldsite.com/content/thisisafile.pdf)). I then upload all assets to Contentful, and replace the links.
Now that I have the entries with links pointing to assets in Contentful I am trying to convert them to Rich Text. This is where I am facing some problems.

I've tried running the markdown-to-richtext converter. It converts all the text/p correctly, however the asset links are returned as a nodeType: "hyperlink" which does not pass validation when trying to update the entry.
I spoke to Contentful suppport, and they suggested replacing "hyperlink" with "asset-hyperlink", but this does not work either.
In both cases it returns an error along the lines of
`hyperlink/asset-hyperlink is not supported. Please use one of the following: paragraph text embedded-asset-block etc.....`

My last attempt was looping through my Rich Text object and completely replacing all hyperlink nodes with an embedded-asset-link which is what the validator suggests. This is accepted by the validator, but it is now complaining about missing a "content" property on the embedded-asset-block:
     `{ "name": "required", "details": "The property \"content\" is required here", "path": [ "fields", "bodyrtf", "en-US", "content", 2, "content" ] } ]'`

This makes no sense for me since the structure of the asset-block is supposed to be like this(As far as I know):

`. { "nodeType": "embedded-asset-block", "data": { "target": { "sys": { "type": "Link", "linkType": "Asset", "id": "exampleAssetId" } } } }`

This is exactly the structure I'm giving it and at this point I'm at a loss. I am also having trouble finding any concrete examples of this in the documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated.